# why it returns me that the index is out of range while I try to sum up the matrix?

Tags: python, list

I want to sum the matrix, bot it returns me that this is out of index... please help me!

plus, it writes me it usually in other tasks I do, what are the possible reasons?

```
matrix=[[1,2,3,4,5], [6,7,8,9,10], [11,12,13,14,15], [16,17,18,19,20], [21,22,23,24,25]]
sum=0
for i in range(len(matrix)):
    for j in range(len(matrix)):

        sum+=[j][i]
print(sum)
```

it gives me time after time the index problem.

Comment: did you mean `for j in range(len(matrix[i])):`?

Comment: You are using `len(matrix)` for both loops, which is fine for a square matrix.

Comment: Try to avoid using *built-in* ```sum``` as the variable name.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to loop over the length of each individual list in the inner loop.

```py
for i in range(len(matrix)):
    for j in range(len(matrix[i])):
        sum += matrix[i][j]
```

However, it is far better to loop over the actual elements rather than the indexes.

```py
for l in matrix: 
    for x in l:
        sum += x
```

Note that you should not overwrite the `sum` builtin function, which can be used to simplify this.

```py
s = 0
for l in matrix: 
    s += sum(l)
```

Further simplification with a generator expression:

```py
s = sum(sum(l) for l in matrix)
```

Comment: You're clearly well-aware of the **actual** problem. Why not talk about that? What you **do** talk about is not a problem for their data.

Comment: In other words, since the question asks for the reason for their error, this answer is just wrong.